# Simple issue with floats and ints

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

A simple question best asked with two lines of code:

```
CGFloat answer = (abs(-27.460757f) - 9.0f) * (800.0f / (46.0f - 9.0f));
    NSLog(@"According to my calculator, answer should be 399.15, but instead it is: %f", answer);
```

When I run this in Xcode (specifically, in the iPhone simulator), I get:

> According to my calculator, answer
>   should be 399.15, but instead it is:
>   389.189209

Is this just due to my lack of understanding of how floats are rounded?

Thanks!

Stewart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `abs()` function operates on integers, so `abs(-27.460757f)` returns 27. Since you’re using floats, use `fabsf()` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was going to be something simple.

Comment: There's also an `ABS` macro in NSObjCRuntime.h, FWIW.